# Highlight tags corresponding to our favorites

Tags: feature-request, design, tag-watching

Each of us have our list of favorite tags.  When a question has tag(s) that match one or more of ours, the background gets highlighted, drawing our attention to the question.

It would also be nice to highlight (perhaps using a bold font) the tags(s) that matched our own, so one could quickly do a further filtering of the question to see if it is of interest at the present time, like the following:

[image]

e.g. **arduino** is in my list of favorites, but the other two in each question are not.

Comment: The real question is "why is arduino on your list of favorites?" ;)  Tongue in cheek, in case you took offense -- I'm actually planning a little educational endeavor, and the easiest platform to run it on, for better or worse, is probably arduino.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I gotta admit, I sort of looked down on Arduino when it first came out, myself being a "professional" and all, but after several clients came to me over a period of a couple years with prototypes already built using one, I gradually acquired a stable of them and am now a fan.  I currently have four, starting with a Uno, then a Mega 2560, and most recently an Arduino 101 using an Intel Curie module (x386 compatible).  Being able to run the same code ***and I/O calls*** over a range from simple 8-bitters to an x86 platform is a pretty good feat.  They are great for prototyping.

Comment: If I can deploy an educational project and not have to support it because the user community provide help faster than I can, that's a win-win for me.  We'll see how that works out!

Answer (score 1):

Worth to mention that it's already being done in the Jobs sidebar widget:

> [image]